# mouth shape is not good

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, mesh, modifiers

i want my mesh mouth look like this but there is problem in my mesh character mouth you can see it in secound picture
[image]

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SNto8tInCks95Y-760n3UugyOjGWwu2_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inverted normals on some of the faces surrounding the mouth. To see this, enable the 'Face Orientation' overlay as shown below.
[image]

Go into Edit mode hit <kbd>A</kbd>
to select All then <kbd>⇧ Shift N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. The result is shown below. (You'll probably need to move the topology of the lips round a bit to improve the result.)
[image]